# 100% image width?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web design and for a class I am creating a site for a restaurant and I made my mockup but I am having issue (or maybe it's not possible) about having my image display as I do in my mockup (image to follow)

Here is the top of my mockup

[image]

I want to have the header 100% (figured that out)
the image 100% width

the image is 1480x808
and with this code it stays 100% width but the height isn't matching up with my next section (it either pushes it off the page entirely or in other resolutions has a big white gap between it and the next section)

Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Would really appreciate it

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#header {
 height: 100px;
 background-image: url(_images/headerpattern.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat;
}
#mainpicture {
 height: 808px;
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 808px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
#redbar {
 height: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #94201f;
}
#slogan {
 height: 207px;
 width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="mainpicture"><img src="_images/mainpic.jpg"  alt="" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="redbar"></div>
  <div id="slogan">Content for  id "slogan" Goes Here</div>
  <div id="redbar"></div>
  
  
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On a non-related note, try to use #mainpicture img{width: 100%;} instead of inline css. It makes your code look a lot cleaner when your further down the line.

Comment: Also in html5 the width attribute should be in pixels so that would be an invalid value (if you use html5)

Comment: thank you for the tip, I know cleaning up my code is something I need to work out.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the height and max-height property from #mainpicture

**Update**

For the red bar I'd remove them from your markup and use `border-bottom` on the first image and `border-bottom` on the second

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1jpdjop/3/)

Comment: I think that did what I was looking for! Thank you.  However, now for some reason my "redbar" divs are not showing up. here is image of what I mean (im using Dreamweaver btw) http://i.imgur.com/iVGrJZj.jpg

Comment: can you put it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure I'll try.  Never heard of jsfiddle before but here goes http://jsfiddle.net/z1jpdjop/

Comment: Ok I updated this again.  I added a div under the second redbar and now they show up but there is a small margin near the top one I am not sure where that is coming from.  http://jsfiddle.net/z1jpdjop/2/

Answer (score 0):

remove the height from #mainpicture.
or 
if you need the height you can try putting the image in background of #mainpicture and set background size cover..Leave the #mainpicture div blank

like

```
<div id="mainpicture"></div>
```

css

```
#mainpicture {
    height: 808px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 808px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image:url(_images/mainpic.jpg);
    background-position:center top;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: `background-size: cover` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your page to be responsive, you must have some rules.

You want the image to show, as well as the slogan area. But the page can be seen in several devices, with several sizes.

So, you should use relative dimensions, so your goal can be achieved trought the many devices...

Place the image inside a div with relative dimensions...